# setBleServiceUuid method in TapKey SDK version 2.17.6

Tags: tapkey

I am using the TapKey SDK in combination with a FlinkeyBox.
So far (SDK 2.12.7), I used to be able to set the BleServiceUuid in the TapkeyEnvironmentConfigBuilder.
Now I've upgraded to the newest SDK version and the method TapkeyEnvironmentConfigBuilder.setBleServiceUuid is simply gone. I can't find it in any migration guide either.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this information is missing. We will cover this in the migration guide.

To change the BLE Service UUID you have now to use the `TapkeyBleAdvertisingFormatBuilder`.

```java
TapkeyBleAdvertisingFormat advertisingFormat = new TapkeyBleAdvertisingFormatBuilder()
  .addV1Format("[serviceUUID]")
  //.addV2Format([domainID])
  .build();

TapkeyServiceFactory tapkeyServiceFactory = new TapkeyServiceFactoryBuilder(this)
  .setBluetoothAdvertisingFormat(advertisingFormat)
...
  .build();
```

New hardware generations will use a new Bluetooth Advertising, which has then to be configured with the V2 format. But for now it will be sufficient just to configure the V1 format. For more informations about how to configure the TapkeyBleAdvertisingFormat please contact your service provider.